# Determine outer boundries of polygon from lat/lng point array

Tags: geospatial, kml

I have a large array of lat/lng points. Could be up to 20k points. I'm plotting them using KML. What I want to do is to take only the outter most points and use them to draw a polygon instead. I already know how to draw a polygon in kml, I just need to figure out how to select only the outer most points of the group.

Any ideas? I'd like to have at least 5 points to the polygon but no more than 25 points total.

So far i've come up with checking for top most and bottom most points (basically crearing a square) using < & > logic.

The points will be in america & canada only if that matters.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I've gotten the Convex Hull algorithm to work, but it isnt exactly what I need. I'm trying to map out zip codes. If a zip code has an L shape then the polygon is going to be a triangle shape and not an L shape. Any ideas?

Comment: If your set of points is sufficiently dense, then you might be able to use an active contour (or "snakes") algorithm to find an acceptable boundary.  You're getting into some fairly advanced image processing techniques at that point.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model for some basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [Convex Hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).  It's not too hard to implement yourself if it's not available in whatever software package you're using.

Comment: thanks. I'm very poor at math so i'll see if I can get an already coded example and let you know what happens.